# Always shows success but not validated correctly - python random

Tags: python-3.x

Always shows success but not validated correctly - python random

```
import random
    
user_name = input("enter your name: ")

print("Hi", user_name)
 
x = random.randrange(9999, 99999)

print("your otp is ", x)

y = input("enter u r otp:")

if x == y:

print("succes")

else:

print("not")
```

not working properly always show sucess

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

user_name = input("enter your name: ")

print("Hi", user_name)

x = random.randrange(9999, 99999)

print("your otp is ", x)

y = input("enter u r otp:")

if str(x) == str(y):

    print("succes")

else:

    print("not")
```

##### convert x into string and y also string